# What's the difference between DECLARE TABLE and CREATE TABLE?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to translate given T-SQL statements into another language. These T-SQL statements are using `DECLARE TABLE`. What's the difference between `DECLARE TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE`?

For example, what’s the difference between the following two lines?

```
declare @t table (account_id varchar(512), num_events int);
```

```
Create table t {account_id varchar(512), num_events int}
```

Comment: Read here for a very detailed answer about Temp Tables Vs Table Variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857789/when-should-i-use-a-table-variable-vs-temporary-table-in-sql-server

Comment: I thought table variable means the variables in the table, now I just knew it means @t here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The only difference between `DECLARE TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` is:

- `DECLARE TABLE`: You will create a table on the fly and use that table later on in the query and not store it physically.
- `CREATE TABLE`: You will create a table physically inside the database.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that "Declare table" would be a table level variable.

The "create table" will create a table in the database.