# SQL alternative to current use of cursor and temp tables

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, cursors

I am going through cleaning up some stored procedures left by prior employees and came across one where I am trying to determine if there is a way it can be handled without the use of a cursor. Currently the cursor looks at a temp table that has a start and end date for each record. It then takes the ID of the record and creates a row with the ID and date for each date that falls in the range of start & end date.

This data is then used create another temp table that stores the ID of the record and the count of distinct dates for each ID.

Could I not just do a `datediff` for the date part days between the start and end dates? I feel like there must be a much better way to derive this information but I'm worried that I may be oversimplifying it and missing something.

Here is the code as it stands now:

```
declare @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime, @ID bigint, @WSIdAndDates cursor 

set @WSIdAndDates = cursor fast_forward for
select servicestartdate, serviceenddate, WorksheetID from #que_rp_claims_dates 

open @WSIdAndDates
fetch next from @WSIdAndDates into @StartDate, @EndDate, @ID 
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

        with ctedaterange 
            as (select [Dates]=@StartDate, 
                @ID[workSheetid]

            union ALL

            select [dates] + 1,
                @ID[workSheetid]
            from ctedaterange 
            where [dates] + 1 <= @EndDate) 

            insert into #tempworksheetidanddates
            select [workSheetid],
                [dates] 
            from ctedaterange 
        option(maxrecursion 0)

    fetch next from @WSIdAndDates into @StartDate, @EndDate, @ID 
end

close @WSIdAndDates
deallocate @WSIdAndDates

select worksheetid, count(distinct(dates)) as LOS into ##que_rp_claims_LOS 
from #tempworksheetidanddates
group by worksheetid
```

The table `##que_rp_claims_LOS` is the only one that gets used outside of this snippet. The other temp table is dropped.

Any insight or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using `DATEDIFF` and test it?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Tom: I did with one data set and the results appear the same, I should have mentioned in my original post, but this is in a stored procedure and I'm trying to determine if there may not be situations where exceptions could cause different results. I was hoping for basically a second (or more) set of eyes to see if I'm not overlooking anything.

And yes KMC, I understand the problem the code block is solving. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process is taking the ID and a start and end date from `#que_rp_claims_dates` and opens a cursor for this.

With each row the same is done: A recursive CTE is collecting/calculating all days from the start date up to the end date and fill this in a table.

In the final step you deliver nothing more than the ID and the count of days.

So I think you are right... If your intermediate results (the temp tables) are not needed anywhere else it should suffice to calculate the `DATEDIFF` for each ID.

#### Attention

If there are `DATETIME` values in use the result might depend on the actual time (if the times are not full day). Look at this especially carefully!

And btw: I appreciate your efforts to get rid of bad stuctures!

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful feedback. It's reassuring that you are seeing the same thing I am. I will continue to test with further data sets but I think a simple `DATEDIFF` will work. There are no `DATETIME` values in use, thankfully.

Answer (score 2):

A better alternative to temporary tables is using table variables. You can declare a table variable like this:

```
DECLARE @tempVariable table(
    WorksheetID int,
    servicestartdate DATE,
    serviceenddate DATE
);
```

And as far as the cursor is concerned, you can always insert all you data in a table variable, use a while to iterate through it and delete the entries just after you have handled them. Something like this:

```
while exists (select top 1 * from tempVariable)
begin
    select top 1 @StartDate = servicestartdate, @EndDate = serviceenddate, @ID = WorksheetID from @tempVariable

    //your code

    DELETE TOP(1) FROM @tempVariable;
end
```

Comment: This statement "A better alternative to temporary tables is using table variables." is a generalization that is absolutely not true. There are times when a table variable is a viable option but there are also times when they absolutely a not a good option. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857789/when-should-i-use-a-table-variable-vs-temporary-table-in-sql-server And you are using TOP with no order by, this is a very bad practice as you need to certain which row will be returned. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/

Comment: Actually I don't need to certain which row will be returned, as I want to go through all rows, retrieving one row at a time. And if you go through all the cases when to use table variables from the post you suggested, I would incline to say table variables are indeed a "better alternative" in this case. :)

Comment: Ahh but it does matter the order in your code. Since you have no order by you cannot be 100% certain that the row you delete is the same one you selected in the select statement. And yes I agree in this situation a table variable is probably the best choice. Your statement suggested they are always better which simply is not true.

Comment: And of course replacing a cursor with a while loop is an exercise in futility. Most of the time a cursor with the right options will out perform a while loop. The best option would be to use set based logic and forget about looping all together. :D