# SQL Server: are temp tables stored in RAM or on disk?

Tags: sql-server

I'm inserting over 10 million rows into a temp table and its size is about 5GB. My computer has 32GB of RAM. Does SQL Server put this table in RAM or on the disk?

Comment: Temp tables will be stored in ram as much as possible but they spill over to disc when needed.

Comment: Are you concerned about performance that could easily be improved by spending a few bucks on hardware? [Get a huge SSD](https://www.amazon.com/SanDisk-Ultra-1TB-SATA-SDSSDHII-1T00-G25/dp/B01N1862SW/ref=sr_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1501267502&sr=1-1&keywords=1tb+ssd). In the words of Jeff Atwood, one of StackOverflow's founders, ["Hardware is Cheap"](https://blog.codinghorror.com/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive/)

Comment: temp tables are **always** stored  on disk.look out this extensive answer on dba,se :https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server and also on SO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857789/when-should-i-use-a-table-variable-vs-temporary-table-in-sql-server

Comment: Not all hardware is cheap--specifically SSD at larger sizes.

Comment: [Agreed](https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2016/8/10/12424666/seagate-60tb-ssd-worlds-largest) @scsimon. But even at the extreme, they're usually a cheaper solution than investing in programmer-hours to make a system more efficient.

Comment: Definitely not arguing the cost benefit against hiring developers, but I just didn't see how that played a part in the OP question is all (since it wasn't even about performance) @BobKaufman. Good links from you though for the OP.

Comment: So... our conclusion is: hardware is cheap and temp tables are stored in tempdb.

Comment: sometimes, and all the time @JacobH hahaha :)

Comment: It's always stored on data pages in `tempdb` but that doesn't mean the pages are actually written to disc. See the end of the dba.se answer for info about that (under "Memory Only?")