# Why joining two table variables significantly increases execution time in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, database-administration

I am extracting data into two table variables `@PremiumData` and `@LossData`. Joining column is `ControlNo`.

If I run them separately, execution time to populate `@PremiumData` is 3 seconds, and execution time to populate `@LossData` is 0 seconds.

But when I join them together via a `left join`, the execution time increases to 01:07 ! minutes.

Query plan can be found here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Syd564Tnf

```
DECLARE
    @EffectiveDateFrom DATETIME = '2012-04-01',
    @EffectiveDateTo DATETIME = '2018-04-30'

DECLARE @PremiumData TABLE (
                            ControlNo int,
                            PolicyNumber varchar(50),
                            EffectiveDate datetime,
                            ExpirationDate datetime,
                            ProducerName varchar(300), 
                            Premium money
                           )
DECLARE @LossData TABLE (
                        ControlNo int,
                        Losses money
                        )

INSERT INTO @PremiumData
    SELECT 
        INV.QuoteControlNum,  
        tblQuotes.PolicyNumber,
        tblQuotes.EffectiveDate,
        (SELECT TOP 1 Q.ExpirationDate
         FROM tblQuotes Q
         WHERE Q.ControlNo = tblQuotes.ControlNo
         ORDER BY Q.QuoteID DESC) as ExpirationDate,
        tblProducers.ProducerName,
        (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(tblFin_InvoiceDetails.AmtBilled), 0)
         FROM tblFin_InvoiceDetails
         WHERE (tblFin_InvoiceDetails.ChargeType = 'P')
           AND (tblFin_InvoiceDetails.InvoiceNum = INV.InvoiceNum)) AS Premium
    FROM            
        tblFin_Invoices INV
    INNER JOIN      
        tblQuotes ON INV.QuoteID = tblQuotes.QuoteID
    INNER JOIN      
        tblProducerLocations ON INV.ProducerLocationGUID = tblProducerLocations.ProducerLocationGUID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        tblProducers WITH (NOLOCK) ON tblProducerLocations.ProducerGUID = dbo.tblProducers.ProducerGUID 
    WHERE 
        (INV.Failed = 0)  
        AND (DATEDIFF(dd, tblQuotes.EffectiveDate, ISNULL(@EffectiveDateTo, tblQuotes.EffectiveDate)) >= 0)
        AND (DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL(@EffectiveDateFrom, tblQuotes.EffectiveDate), tblQuotes.EffectiveDate) >= 0)
        AND dbo.tblQuotes.CompanyLocationGUID IN ('32828BB4-E1FA-489F-9764-75D8AF7A78F1',--"Plaza Insurance Company"    
                                                  '54A8FCCD-C7FE-4642-9C22-3A25207CDAEE' -- Watford         
                                                 )   

INSERT INTO @LossData
    SELECT 
        CPI.ControlNumber,
        SUM(CRP.ResPayAmount) as [Losses]
    FROM
        tblClaims_Claim C
    INNER JOIN 
        tblClaims_PolicyInformation CPI ON CPI.ClaimId = C.ClaimId
    INNER JOIN 
        tblClaims_ReservePayments CRP ON CRP.ClaimId = C.ClaimId
    GROUP BY
        CPI.ControlNumber--,

/* Joining @PremiumData and @LossData*/
SELECT  
    p.PolicyNumber,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),p.EffectiveDate,101) as EffectiveDate,
    YEAR(EffectiveDate) as EffectiveYear,
    MONTH(EffectiveDate) as EffectiveMonth,
    SUBSTRING('JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC ', (MONTH(EffectiveDate) * 4) - 3, 3) as MonthShort,
    'Q' + CONVERT(CHAR(1),DATEPART(QUARTER, p.EffectiveDate)) as Quarter,
    p.ProducerName,
    SUM(p.Premium) as Premium,
    ISNULL(ROUND(dbo.fn_EarnedPremiumCalcExtendedPolicies(SUM(Premium), EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate, 0, GETDATE()), 2), SUM(Premium)) AS EarnedPremium,   
    ISNULL(l.Losses,0) as Losses,
    ISNULL(SUM(l.Losses), 0) / NULLIF(ISNULL(ROUND(dbo.fn_EarnedPremiumCalcExtendedPolicies(SUM(Premium), EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate, 0, GETDATE()), 2), SUM(Premium)),0) as LossRatio
FROM 
    @PremiumData p
LEFT JOIN 
    @LossData l ON p.ControlNo = l.ControlNo 
GROUP BY  --p.ControlNo
    p.PolicyNumber,
    p.EffectiveDate,
    p.ExpirationDate,
    p.ProducerName,
    l.Losses
```

This is also the part of execution plan that concerns me:

[image]

Comment: try using temp # table instead of table variables since table variables have a performance issue for high number of rows and especially the cardinality estimation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the estimated number of rows for your table variables in the execution plan you linked.  The estimates are 1 row, but the actual rows are much higher.

The issue is the cardinality estimate is way off.  I imagine the query is causing a spill into temp db because the initial memory grant is just too low.  There are some [helpful answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857789/when-should-i-use-a-table-variable-vs-temporary-table-in-sql-server)

Try temp tables instead of table variables.

You could also try adding `option(recompile)` at the end of your `insert` statements (table variable or temp table) and this should improve your cardinality estimates.

Edit based on your edit:  That sort is suffering from a bad cardinality estimate as well.  The sort exists because you are grouping the query where you join the two table variables.

Comment: By using #TempTables the execution time now is 3 seconds. Awesome. Thank you